# AJAX request in random moments and order and MongoDB write epipe issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, mongodb

I work on 2 connected web apps in NodeJS. Let's call them A and B. Most of it works, but...

In app A there is a video stream and the user can ask a question in the form. I use jquery and ajax to submit the form and send a post request, that inserts a question into MongoDB - each as a separate document. App B reads the questions from the collection using jquery and ajax as well. It makes a get request every 5 seconds - I used `setInterval`. And here we go.

When I start both apps they work for some time, BUT randomly app A sends a post request with a question added previously. Sometimes app B erases all documents from DB, etc. I guess there is logic behind this, but I can't see it.

Below are the problematic pieces of code.

**App A**

API part:

```js
    index.post('/ask', (req, res) => {
      var question = req.body.question;
      var person = req.body.person;

        mongo.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true}, (err, dbo) => {
          if(err) return;
          else{
            var db = dbo.db('question');
            db.collection('asked').insertOne({question:question, who:person}, (err) => {
              if(err) return;

            })
          }
        })
    })
```

ajax part:

```js
      $('#ask_question').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();

        var question = $('#inputDefault').val();
        var who = $('#exampleSelect1').val();
        console.log(question + ' '+ who);
        $.ajax({
          url: '/ask',
          method: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json',
          data: JSON.stringify({
            question: question,
            person:who
          }),
          success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
          }
        });
      });
```

**App B**

API:

```js
    index.get('/asked', (req, res) => {
        mongo.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true}, (err, dbo) => {
          if(err) return;
          else{
            var db = dbo.db('question');
            db.collection('asked').find({}).toArray((err, result) => {
              if(err) return;
              if(!result) return;
              else res.send(result);
          })
        }
      })
    })
```

ajax part:

```js
    setInterval(()=>{
    $.ajax({
      url: '/asked',
      method:'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      async: false,
      success: function(response) {
        var form = $('#asked');
        $('#asked').empty();
        $.each(response, function(i, question) {
          form.append('<li>'+question.question+ ' ('+question.who+')</li>');
        });
      }
    });
    },5000);
```

If you're wondering why I use `return` it's because I'm trying to prevent MongoDB from crashing. After some time (like 15 minutes or so) I get an error:

```sh
.../node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/mongo_client_ops.js:474
      throw err;
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:870:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:893:20)
    at WriteWrap.afterWrite (net.js:763:14)
```

It happens in both apps. I guess it's a simple deadlock, but don't know how to prevent this.

If you want I'll provide a bigger part of the project. I can't figure out solutions for these problems.

Comment: Any particular reason as to why you make a new connection for each request? 1 connection for each app should suffice I guess.

Comment: also don't if(err) return; but send a proper 500 if you couldnot fulfill the user request (although he asked nicely and correctly). e.g ```if(err) return res.status(500).send('or something')```

Comment: @AmitDas I need data to be up to date. I don't know any way to send multiple repsponses on one ajax request.

Comment: @user753642 I did, what you wrote. Thanks a lot. It has helped. Now there is no randomness in sending responses. I need to solve one more problem with mongo - it can't handle so many requests. Being more specify, mongo refuses to connect

Comment: it has been highlighted by @Amit Das already. You probably do not need to create a connection for every client request. (e.g once connected, keep your handle. If you look at mongoose, there is a pool of 5 connections rolling to handle the incoming (db)requests)

Comment: Forgot to mention. All problem solved. I did few stupid things and connections to mongo haven't been closed. Mongo just couldn't handle so many connections and it was cause of crushing. I've corrected it and now everyhting works as it should from the beginning. Just beginners things. Thank you all for help.